# why other web project show me logged in?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on two separated web projects, but use same authentication scenario for both of them. 
Here is a part of my login code:

```
public void Login(string username, string password, bool staySignedIn)
{
    if (this.IsLockedOut(username))
    {
        this._view.ShowMessage("Your account has been locked!");
        return;
    }
    else if (!this.IsApproved(username))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.webContext.CurrentUserID))
        {
            this.membershipService.ChangeApprove(this.webContext.CurrentUserIdFromQuery);
            this.DoLogin(username, password, staySignedIn);
        }
        else
            this._view.ShowMessage("Your account is not activated yet");
    }
    else
        this.DoLogin(username, password, staySignedIn);
}

private void DoLogin(string username, string password, bool staySignedIn)
{
    try
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, staySignedIn);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.webContext.GetReturnUrl))
            this.redirector.GotoUrl(this.webContext.GetReturnUrl);
        else this.redirector.GotoProfileDefault();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logger.PrintToLogFile(ex, false);
        this._view.ShowMessage("Some error code");
    }
}
```

In project1, I have 3 users: user1, user2 and user3 and no user in project2 . My problem is: when I login to web project1 as user1, if web project2 is view in browser, it shows me logged in too as user1 with same user data in project1.Some thing like I login in both webs. and I don't know why. May you please give me any suggestion?

Comment: no, this is only code that I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the web projects are running in localhost. Am I wrong? I suppose you access to test requesting this url `http://localhost:XXXx` So as you have stored a login cookie for one website, if the other runs in localhost domain too, this site checks the cookie you already have.

I advice you remove sessions and cookies before test each site.

Other good way is create fake domains in your local web server, and edit hosts file to point the domains to 127.0.0.1 and test the sites writing in navigator each and different fake domain

Comment: As Alberto suggests. Create fake domains in your hosts file. I use things like `http://project1.local.com` to point to ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Alberto: yes, you are right. Projects are running in localhost. Can I change the cookie name for each one to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH I'm not sure because is a standard behaviour of MembershipProviders... but the best practice is fake domains. This will solve you a lot of problems in future

Comment: @Mazdak_SH: yes, you can change the name of the cookie so that each applications use a unique cookie name. Look for the `name` attribute in the `forms` node of the authentication section.

Comment: Thank you Alberto very much. Your suggestion marked as answer. Do you know any reference to guide me to create a fake domains?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thanks for your response, you mean in web.config?

Comment: @Mazdak_SH this post in mojoportal should be useful for you http://www.mojoportal.com/adding-a-host-name-to-the-hosts-file-for-local-testing